# Process monitoring - Python/Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, process-management, upstart

I have a few processes I need to run in deamon mode, I just discovered upstart so I am starting to use it.

---

**Are there any python libraries or applications that I could use to monitor and control these processes from an html interface?**

I'm asking as I would like to prevent myself from reinventing the wheel. :)

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain the programming portion of this question, as I must be missing it. If it doesn't have one, perhaps ask it on either http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com or http://linux.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are some, but be aware that controlling processes, in a secure way, from a web interface is tricky. The web server typically runs as non-root, and won't be able to to control most other processes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is pretty awesome. I haven't used the web interface though, it might suck.

Comment: +1 Supervisor is great. The webinterface was pretty from what I can remember. One could easily write another one and use XML-RPC to control supervisor, if it didn't suffice.

Answer (score 10):

I think [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) is what you are looking for.

Comment: happy you like it ;) please accept the answer if you want

Comment: indeed I will! Was just waiting a few minutes just in case something else turned up. :P

Comment: ah, ok perfect ;) i had bad experiences ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try [circus](https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus).

Cheers
Laidback