# Simple remote process monitoring with Python

Tags: python, linux, monitoring

I'd like to write a python script to perform some very simple "agentless" monitoring of remote processes running on linux servers.

It would perform the following tasks, in psuedocode:

```
for each remoteIPAddress in listOfIPAddresses:
    log into server@remoteIPAddress via ssh
    execute the equivalent of a 'ps -ef' command
    grep the result to make sure a particular process (by name) is still running
```

One way to do this is to have python call shell scripts in a subprocess and parse their output.
That seems pretty inefficient.  Is there a better way to do this via python libraries?

All I could find via research here and elsewhere was:

- [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)  - looks like it doesn't do remote monitoring, so I'd have to run agents on the remote machines to report stats back via RPC.
- [pymeter](http://pymeter.sourceforge.net/docs.html) - I would have to write my own plugin for monitoring a specific remote service.
- [stackoverflow #4546492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546492/process-monitoring-python-ubuntu-linux) - Some helpful links but the poster was looking for a different solution.

Thanks, and please go easy on me, it's my first question :-)

Comment: http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/ is also a gud option I guess

Comment: Thanks.  I've downloaded it and will evaluate in parallel with Fabric (below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html) library may be of interest to you.

Comment: +1 to Fabric, makes such thing way more efficient to write and maintain in place of shell scripts from Python.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Looks like I will still need to do the core of it using ssh commands but Fabric wraps this much more elegantly than I could have hoped to kluge together myself.  Appreciate the prompt suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/). You can use it to ssh into the server and run commands. You can then parse the results and do what you'd like with them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think I'll start with Fabric but this is plan B and a good answer.

Comment: Looked into both Fabric and Paramiko.  I am accepting this answer because it conforms most closely to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Taking cues from the answers above, I investigated Fabric and found the following presentation particularly interesting/helpful.  It is an overview of three libraries -- Fabric, Cuisine, and Watchdog -- for server monitoring and administration.
For posterity:

[Using Fabric, Cuisine, and Watchdog for server administration in Python](http://www.slideshare.net/ffunction/fabric-cuisine-and-watchdog-for-server-administration-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It might be heavier than what you're looking for, but [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) supports agentless monitoring.

paramiko and Fabric, suggested in the other answers, are great options too.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like a commercial product so I'll keep this in my notebook for scaling later on.

Comment: It's open source, but they do have a commercial edition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a dedicated monitoring tool like Nagios ? 
Nagios has agent and agent less monitoring through NRPE plugins and SSH plugins etc.
Try it out.